# Passing ArrayList through Intent

Tags: android, arraylist, android-intent

I am trying to pass an arrayList to another activity using intents. Here is the code in the first activity.

```
case R.id.editButton:
        Toast.makeText(this, "edit was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, editList.class);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("stock_list", stock_list);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
```

This is where I try to retrieve the list in the second activity. Is something wrong here?

```
Intent i = new Intent(); //This should be getIntent();
    stock_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    stock_list = i.getStringArrayListExtra("stock_list");
```

Answer (score 109, accepted):

In your receiving intent you need to do:

```
Intent i = getIntent();  
stock_list = i.getStringArrayListExtra("stock_list");
```

The way you have it you've just created a new empty intent without any extras.

If you only have a single extra you can condense this down to:

```
stock_list = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("stock_list");
```

Answer (score 24):

I have done this one by  **Passing ArrayList** in form of **String**.

1. Add `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'` in **dependencies** block **build.gradle**.
2. **Click** on **Sync Project with Gradle Files**

**Cars.java**:

```
public class Cars {
    public String id, name;
}
```

## FirstActivity.java

When you **want** to **pass** **ArrayList**:

```
List<Cars> cars= new ArrayList<Cars>();
cars.add(getCarModel("1", "A"));
cars.add(getCarModel("2", "B"));
cars.add(getCarModel("3", "C"));
cars.add(getCarModel("4", "D"));

Gson gson = new Gson();

String jsonCars = gson.toJson(cars);

Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("list_as_string", jsonCars);
startActivity(intent);
```

Get **CarsModel** by **Function**:

```
private Cars getCarModel(String id, String name){
       Cars cars = new Cars();
       cars.id = id;
       cars.name = name;
    return cars;
 }
```

## SecondActivity.java

You have to import `java.lang.reflect.Type` ;

on **onCreate()** to retrieve **ArrayList**:

```
String carListAsString = getIntent().getStringExtra("list_as_string");

Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<List<Cars>>(){}.getType();
List<Cars> carsList = gson.fromJson(carListAsString, type);
for (Cars cars : carsList){
   Log.i("Car Data", cars.id+"-"+cars.name);
}
```

Hope this will save time, I saved it.

**Done**

Comment: Or you can simply have your Cars model class implement Parcelable interface and simply do intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("parecelable_list", carsList); where carsList is an instance of ArrayList<Cars>

Comment: Downvoter should take care of adding comment as reason.

Comment: Why would I use Gson if there is already `intent.putStringArrayListExtra`, `intent.getStringArrayListExtra` or `getSerializableExtra` exists. And what if I use eclipse? I have to download and add Gson library?

Comment: My 2 bits... You can't down vote this for that reason, but you should recommend Parceling over Serializing as its been proved many times over - for Android its more efficient & out performs Serialization.

Answer (score 13):

if you using **Generic Array List** with **Class** instead of **specific type** like

**EX:**

```
private ArrayList<Model> aListModel = new ArrayList<Model>();
```

Here, **Model = Class**

Receiving Intent Like :

```
aListModel = (ArrayList<Model>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(KEY);
```

**MUST REMEMBER:**

Here Model-class must be implemented like:
 ***ModelClass implements Serializable***

Comment: Normally like Sending Intent for **startActivityForResult**:

`Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);  
startActivityForResult(intent, aListModel);`

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you need to pass an arraylist of following class from current activity to next activity 
// class of the objects those in the arraylist
// remember to implement the class from Serializable interface
// Serializable means it converts the object into stream of bytes and helps to transfer that object

```
public class Question implements Serializable {
... 
... 
...
}
```

in your current activity you probably have an ArrayList as follows

```
ArrayList<Question> qsList = new ArrayList<>();
qsList.add(new Question(1));
qsList.add(new Question(2));
qsList.add(new Question(3));

// intialize Bundle instance
Bundle b = new Bundle();
// putting questions list into the bundle .. as key value pair.
// so you can retrieve the arrayList with this key
b.putSerializable("questions", (Serializable) qsList);
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
i.putExtras(b);
startActivity(i);
```

in order to get the arraylist within the next activity

```
//get the bundle
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
//getting the arraylist from the key
ArrayList<Question> q = (ArrayList<Question>) b.getSerializable("questions");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
//arraylist/Pojo you can Pass using bundle  like this 
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle args = new Bundle();
                        args.putSerializable("imageSliders",(Serializable)allStoriesPojo.getImageSliderPojos());
                        intent.putExtra("BUNDLE",args);
 startActivity(intent); 


Get SecondActivity like this
  Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle args = intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");
String filter = bundle.getString("imageSliders");

//Happy coding
```

Comment: It is throwing an exception:
 `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.ModelObjectNameHere cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable`

Answer (score 2):

```
    public class StructMain implements Serializable {
    public  int id;
    public String name;
    public String lastName;
}
```

this my item . implement Serializable
and create ArrayList

```
ArrayList<StructMain> items =new ArrayList<>();
```

and put in Bundle

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("test",items);
```

and create a new Intent that put Bundle to Intent

```
Intent intent=new Intent(ActivityOne.this,ActivityTwo.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

for receive bundle insert this code

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
ArrayList<StructMain> item = (ArrayList<StructMain>) bundle.getSerializable("test");
```