# Sending arrayList<string> with intent

Tags: android, arraylist

I have made a list of names that I need to send to a different activity like this:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
 imena[i] = player[i].toString();
}
    allPlayers = new ArrayList<String>();
    Collection l = Arrays.asList(imena);
    allPlayers.addAll(l);
```

I'm not sure if this is correct, but then in the other activity I need to set the text of dynamically made EditText boxes to the names that I have set to my list, this is my try:

```
if(bundle!= null)
    {   


        allPlayers = bundle.getStringArrayList("allPlayers");
        for (i = 0;i<n;i++)
        {
                player[i] = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
                player[i].setTextSize(20);
                String p1 = allPlayers.get(i).toString();
                player[i].setText(p1);
                root.addView(player[i]);


        }
    }
```

As a result I get the EditBoxes filled with the text: "Android.widget.EditText{4085a09....}"
any ideas how to get the actual names in those boxes?

Comment: Whatever `player[i]` is, use a better method than `#toString()`.

Comment: I think this will be helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374546/passing-arraylist-through-intent

Comment: EditText[] player  = new EditText[16]; @MattBall

Comment: http://androidhub.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/android-intents-for-passing-data-between-activities-part-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
 imena[i] = player[i].toString();
```

Note that `player` is an array of EditText, not String, so you need to call `player[i].getText().toString()` rather than `player[i].toString()` to get the value of the EditText.

Comment: If resolved, it is appropriate to accept Peter's vote with the checkmark so that he gets credit for doing so.