# Pass double type arraylist to intent

Tags: java, android, arraylist

How do I pass an `ArrayList` of type double in intent?

```
intent.putExtra("NUTRI_CONTENTS", nContentList);
```

and in another activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    ArrayList<Double> nContentList = (ArrayList<Double>) intent.getExtras().getSerializable("NUTRI_CONTENTS");
```

But this returns `null`.

Comment: show your code. It looks you might simply not pass intent...

Comment: I have already showed with code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing ArrayList through Intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374546/passing-arraylist-through-intent)

Comment: in  [Passing ArrayList through Intent] its passing String arraylist. i want to pass Double ArrayList.

Comment: This is not duplicate. In  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374546/passing-arraylist-through-intent) its passing String arraylist. i want to pass Double ArrayList. For ArrayList<String> there is method called putStringArrayListExtra, but there is no such methods for Double

Answer (score 1):

If you pass an `ArrayList` in the Intent, you can, as you've done, get back this `ArrayList` from the other `Activity`, using `getExtras().getSerializable()` as an `ArrayList` implements `Serializable`according to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html).

If you get null from the other `Activity`, maybe it's because your `ArrayList` (nContentList) is null?

Comment: No @Jeje. ArrayList has values.