# Android passing ArrayList<Object> within Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, parcelable, serializable

I know that there are 2 ways to do this, Parcelable and Serializable. Another method (a bad one) is static variables.

An entry of that list can be instance of class A or class B.

I tried passing the list using Parcelable and Serializable with no success, since the class Object doesn't implement anything.

```
// When setting:

List<Object> liveMatchList = DataCenter.getMatchesByDate(context, date,
                    tIdsAsString, true);
intent.putExtra("SER", liveMatchList);

// When getting:

List<Object> matchesList = (List<Object>)intent.getSerializableExtra("SER");
```

How to do this please?

Comment: Paste your code please?

Comment: Use `Parcelable`. You have awesome method `Intent#putParcelableArrayListExtra`

Comment: I've updated my question, it's only List<Object>, it cant be parcelable as I'm using the class 'Object' that's not parcelable.

Answer (score 0):

try with below code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,DESTINATION ACTIVITY.class);
intent.putExtra("data",YOUR ARRAY OF OBJECT)
startActivity(intent);
```

//Getting data in another activity

```
ARRAY OF OBJECT = (ArrayList<String>) this.getIntent().getSerializableExtra("data");
```

//here I` have used Arraylist to explain you.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm forced to use ArrayList<Object> (specifically <Object>)

Comment: @HamzehSoboh Ya because I think you can not pass with custom objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = getIntent();  
stock_list = i.getStringArrayListExtra("stock_list");
and 
stock_list = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("stock_list");
```

[Passing ArrayList through Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374546/passing-arraylist-through-intent)