# Two ListViews in two activities with same Values

Tags: php, android, listview

I am doing an android project using `php`,`mysql` using `xamp` server. I have retrieved the values into a `ListView` from server database using json parser and displayed them successfully in *activity1*.

Now i need codings for, "when i press a button it should navigate into a new page named *activity2* and the `ListView` values in *activity1* should display in new `ListView` *on activity2*.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look in this link
[passing-arraylist-through-intent][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374546/passing-arraylist-through-intent

Comment: either do that what is told above...or just make that arraylist static ...then you can access it from other class..

Answer (score 0):

in your starting intent you need to add data in intent :

```html
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, abc.class);
  intent.putExtra("data", data);
   startActivity(intent);
```

In your receiving intent you need to do:

```html
Intent i = getIntent();  
stock_list = i.getStringArrayListExtra("data");
```

The way you have it you've just created a new empty intent without any extras.

If you only have a single extra you can condense this down to:

stock_list = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("data");

Comment: super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_token);
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();     
        Intent i = getIntent();  
        list= i.getStringArrayListExtra("list");
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(token.this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter); is there any mistakes in this code because its autoamtically closing when this activity is open

Comment: check out the the debug that will track you that where is problem

Comment: Excuse me What is stock_list here..where does it came from??and what will be its future function?

Answer (score 0):

Make a static function which contains the data for the list view and call the same function in the both activities. Hope it will solve you problem.