# How to parse Uri ArrayList<Uri>?

Tags: android

i have an image uri which are store in Arraylist and i put this Arraylist in the intent using putExtra().but i have no idea how to get ArrayList in uri form??

```
    else if(data!=null){

       clipData = data.getClipData();
       ArrayList<Uri> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();             

        for(int i=0;i<clipData.getItemCount();i++){

             Uri uri=clipData.getItemAt(i).getUri();
             arrayList.add(uri);
       }
         Intent intent=new Intent(getBaseContext(),BackUp_Main.class);
         intent.putExtra("multipleImage",arrayList);
         startActivity(intent);
   }
```

how can i get Arraylist in Uri from??

Comment: I can't understand you, you can get the arraylist in backup_main.class by using intent.getExtra("multipleImage");

Comment: ArrayList<Uri> myList = (ArrayList<Uri>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("multipleImage");

Comment: Send as string arraylist.tostring() when putextra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From BackUp_Main activity, you can receive this arraylist like following:

```
list = (ArrayList<Uri>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(YOUR_KEY);
```

Read this article for more:
[Passing ArrayList through Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374546/passing-arraylist-through-intent)

Answer (score 1):

`Intent` provides methods to put different ArrayLists into it. As `Uri` implements `Parcelable` you should use `putParcelableArrayListExtra()`:

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("multipleImage", arrayList);
ArrayList<Uri> arrayList = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("multipleImage");
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert each uri into string and then put string array into intent. You can also extract string arrat and parse uris from it