# Pass EditText value from ListView to another Activity

Tags: android, csv

I have three activities. In one `Activity`, I read data from `CSV` file and using `ListView`, I am showing it in `EditText`. Now, I want to pass value of `EditText` to another `Activity`. What can be done to solve this problem?

Code:

```
    String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/grocery/data/" + spinner.toString();

    final File csvfile = new File(dir.toString());

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    MyList adapter = new MyList(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.activity_editfeild);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    studentid= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_studentid);
    Schoolname= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_schoolname);
    schoolAdress= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_schooladd);
    studentname=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_studentname);
    fathername= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_fathername);
    mothername= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_mothername);
    studentaddress= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_studentadd);

 //Toast.makeText(Editinfo.this, studentid.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(csvfile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(inputStream);

    final List<String[]> myList=reader.read();

    for (String[] data : myList) {
        adapter.add(data);
    }

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Editinfo1.class);

            intent.putExtra("spinner", chosenOption);

            intent.putExtra("studentid", studentid.getText().toString());

            intent.putExtra("schoolname", Schoolname.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("schooladdress", schoolAdress.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("studentname", studentname.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("fathername", fathername.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("mothername", mothername.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("studentaddress", studentaddress.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("myList", (Serializable) myList);
            //intent.putExtra("mylist", myList);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you pass that list item position and your arraylist using intent and in next activity you get that arraylist and position and get value from your arraylist using received position.

Comment: Thanks...can u give brief idea about how to pass item position

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374546/passing-arraylist-through-intent

Comment: thnks i will go though it..

Comment: thanks for sharing the link..its help to me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify your adapter like the following code :

Define new `ArrayList`:
`Private List<String> listItemChosen = new ArrayList<>();`

Create method that return list :

```
private List<String> getSelectedString(){
        return listItemChosen;
    }
```

in your onClick do like below :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.MODE_SHARED, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
final SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
final Gson gson = new Gson();

holder.tvItemName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    listItemChosen.add(itemName);
                    String jsonString = gson.toJson(getSelectedString());
                    edit.putString(Constants.KEY_SHARED,jsonString);
                    edit.commit();
                }
            });
```

That code above just in adding condition. Every click in `textview`, it always save the selected item in your list.

if you need remove item that has been added, you should add parameter again like `int` parameter, First click it will add item, and the second click on same textview it will delete the item.

I have a reference look like what you need, but [HERE](http://androidbie.blogspot.co.id/2016/12/android-get-value-of-list-checkbox-and.html) using checkbox. But generally, the logic still same.

let me know if there something missed