# Intent values (json array) to Listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-activity

Is it possible to put `Intent` values from one `Activity` to a `ListView` in another `Activity`?

Here are the values from `Activity1` that I wanted to put to the `ListView` in `Activity2`:

```
       try
        {
        jsonobject = new JSONObject(json);
        jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("user");
        JSONObject jb= jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);
        //Username = jb.getString("Username");
        Password = jb.getString("Password");
        Fullname = jb.getString("Fullname");
        Email = jb.getString("Email");
        Bio = jb.getString("Bio");
        Location = jb.getString("Location");


        fn.setText(Fullname);
        em.setText(Email);
        loc.setText(Location);
        b.setText(Bio);

        if(json!=null)
        {
            Intent i = new 
  Intent(HomePageActivity.this,ProfileActivity.class);
            i.putExtra(u.username(), u.getUsername());
            i.putExtra("password",Password);
            i.putExtra("fullname",Fullname);
            i.putExtra("email", Email);
            i.putExtra("bio", Bio);
            i.putExtra("location", Location);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }



        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Add your values into `ArrayList<String>`, Pass to another activity using `Intent`, retrieve List of Strings into another activity and bind the values into `ListView`

Comment: Even doing it the way you have done is also fine. What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I finally displayed the arraylist values to the listview!! Thank you guys

Answer (score 2):

You can put intent values from one activity to a listview in another activity.

From another activity, you can use `getIntent().getExtras().getString("key...");`. But this can be only one line.

For sending array, you should see [Sending arrays with Intent.putExtra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848148/sending-arrays-with-intent-putextra).

For sending arraylist, [Passing ArrayList through Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374546/passing-arraylist-through-intent).

I hope this may help you.

Comment: Is this the right way of passing my arraylist through intent? Here is my updated code: https://pastebin.com/Gu88pBtW

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. I can see that you want to pass all the values of your `user` `object` to another activity using `intent`. You can pass the individual values like you are doing above OR You can pass the user object directly as -

```
i.putExtra("MyClass", u); //u is the user object here
```

You can get back your `user` object in the target activity as -

```
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyClass"); //Make sure that your user model class implements serializable
```

If it is a listview of users, you can add this user object to your array of users. This is the array that you must have set to your adapter in target activity. Now you can call -

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This will make the new changes in your listview. Thanks.